# In Altair / Vega, is there a way to run arbitrary Javascript code on click?

Tags: javascript, python, vega, altair

I'd like to have a visualization I created with Altair be clickable, and execute an action when I click on certain areas of the chart. Specifically, I want to scroll to certain points in a text box when parts of the chart are clicked. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, sort of: Vega (the library that renders Altair/Vega-Lite charts) has a well defined signal API that you can read about here: https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/#signals. This allows you to define custom javascript callbacks for signals generated via interaction with the chart.

However, there is no high-level interface to this in Vega-Lite or Altair, so to use it you'll have to work directly with the view API in the Javascript that renders the chart.

If you want to do this from Altair, the best approach would probably be:

- define your Altair chart, and export it to JSON with `chart.to_json()`
- write separate HTML/Javascript that ingests this JSON and renders the chart, using [vega-embed](https://github.com/vega/vega-embed)
- in this rendering script, make use of the [View API](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/#signals) to attach custom Javascript callbacks to signals generated by the chart.